# How does one look up documentation for infix operators in R?

Tags: r

Normally when I want to look up a function's documentation in `R`, I can just type `?lm`, or to do a search for it among various packages, I can type `??lm`. However, this does not appear to work for infix operators. For example, when I do `?%*%`, I get the following message.

```
> ?%*%
Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "?%*%"
```

Is there a way to look up documentation for such functions / operators in general in `R`?

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm not sure how I was expected to know this a priori.

Comment: @AnandaMahto: post as answer please ...

Comment: If Ananda doesn't post his comment as an answer in a few more minutes, I'll go ahead and accept the answer below.

Comment: You may also wish to read [this](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Getting-help). '"For a feature specified by special characters, the argument must be enclosed in double or single quotes, making it a “character string”' And from the `help` help pages: "Some topics need to be quoted (by backticks) or given as a character string.".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For basic operators you need to put quotes around them.

Also here is [a list of R base package](http://www.math.montana.edu/Rweb/Rhelp/00Index.html) functions for you to play around with.

```
?"%*%"
# matmult {base}    R Documentation
# Matrix Multiplication ... 

? "'"
# Quote
# Quotes {base} R Documentation
# Quotes ...
```

Also has hadley mentioned:

```
?"?"
# Question {utils}  R Documentation
# Documentation Shortcuts ...
?"??"
# help.search {utils}   R Documentation
# Search the Help System
```